# Where is the function continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function defined as

$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}$

Where is this function continuous?

Comment: Where is this function defined? It clearly isn't defined, for example, on $x=-1$...

Comment: try some specific cases, say "a small $x$", and "a large $x$". What is threshold between the two cases?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, we can compute the limit function $f(x)$.

If $|x|\lt 1$, then $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so $f(x)=0$.

Clearly if $x=1$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$,

If $x=-1$, the sequence is not even defined for odd $n$. So the limit does not exist.

If $|x|\gt 1$, divide top and bottom by $x^n$. We get 
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^n}+1}.$$
As $n\to\infty$, $\frac{1}{x^n}\to 0$. It follows that $f(x)=1$.

Now that we know $f(x)$ for all $x$, it should not be difficult to find where $f(x)$ is continuous, and where it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Can you find the pointwise limit?

**Hint**: Look at the separate cases for $0\leq x <1$, $x=1$ and $x>1$.